# Uses of foreachRDD foreachPartition in pyspark streaming benefits aside from output/connections

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My `Apache spark` streaming code operates on the `Dstream`, as follows below. My question is whether there is any value in using `foreachRDD` which is understand can only be performed on the driver. Of course like the documentation, perhaps for opening a connection less frequently may be useful. But the usecase is very massively parallel process - each one will write to a db table. I appreciate I could use `foreachPartition` to reduce the number of DB connections, but is there anything I am missing here?

```
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "test")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
line_split = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split("\n"))
process = line_split.flatMap(lambda record: ProcessA(record)).map(lambda tran: ProcessB(tran))
```

Here `ProcessA` will effectively unwind the incoming data structure and `ProcessB` will then process these unwound structures. Currently the DB connection is done for each of the `ProcessB` calls - which I will consider rewriting to avoid the DB load.

So apart from using `foreachPartition` to reduce the DB connections - is there any speed advantage?